# Using Regular Expression replacing with another regex

Tags: java, regex

Hello i am trying to replace wrongly inserted currency amounts in correct format and if the format is correct is must do nothing, so i wrote this code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegexReplace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = null;
        Matcher matcher = null;
        String regExp = "^([0-9]{2,3})\\.([0-9]{3})\\.([0-9]{2})$||^([0-9]{2,3})\\,([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})$||^([0-9]{2,3})\\.([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})$";

        String replacement = "($1\\,$2\\.$3)"; 
        String patternText[] = {"14.978.00", "14,97800", "14.97800", "14,978.00"};
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
        for(String text : patternText){
            matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            System.out.println(text +" : " + matcher.matches());

            String value = text;
            if (value != null) {
                value = pattern.matcher(value).replaceAll(replacement);
                text = value;
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

the output of this code is coming as:

```
14.978.00 : true
14,978.00,.
14,97800 : true
,.1,.4,.,,.9,.7,.8,.0,.0,.
14.97800 : true
,.1,.4,..,.9,.7,.8,.0,.0,.
14,978.00 : false
,.1,.4,.,,.9,.7,.8,..,.0,.0,.
```

whereas the expected output is like:

```
14.978.00 : true
14,978.00
14,97800 : true
14,978.00
14.97800 : true
14,978.00
14,978.00 : false
no changes
```

Comment: The code for recognizing the currency amount is correct, what i am struck with is with correcting the incorrect currency amounts.

Comment: While I am sure that regexes can be used here, I would assume that `DecmalFormat` is easier to use for formatting the output.

Comment: There are few problems with your regex. First you are using `a||b` which means `a` or `emptyString ""` or `b`. If you want to say `a` or `b` then use single pipe like `a|b`. Also in your regex you are using `($1\\,$2\\.$3)` as replacement, but group 1 exists only in first case of your regex. Groups after first `|` are indexed 4,5,6 and after another `|` 7,8,9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{2,3})[.,]?(\\d{3})[.,]?(\\d{2})$");
String replacement = "$1,$2.$3";

String[] samples = {"14.978.00", "14,97800", "14.97800", "14,978.00"};
for (String sample : samples) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);
    System.out.println(sample + "\t= " + matcher.replaceAll(replacement));
}
```